# Is there a way to make a tkinter scrollbar flat?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

So I want to find out if there's a way to make the python tkinter scrollbar flat. The scrollbar that I get is just like any other:
[This is the scrollbar that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gxSd.png)

The code for this was:

```
albums_var = tkinter.Variable(root)
albums_var.set(("Choose an artist",))
albums_list = tkinter.Listbox(root, listvariable=albums_var, font=("Myriad Pro", 20))
albums_list.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew', padx=(30, 0))
albums_list.config(border=2, relief='flat')

albums_scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=albums_list.yview)
albums_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nse', rowspan=1)
albums_scrollbar.config(relief='flat')
albums_list['yscrollcommand'] = albums_scrollbar.set
```

And I want something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfmlM.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `activerelief`. Set the parameter to flat, and you should get your desired output.

Full code:

```py
albums_scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(root, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=albums_list.yview, relief = "flat")
```

Hope this helps!